# ios9 - Multiple WkWebView sharing cookie WKProcessPool() doesn't work?

Tags: cookies, wkwebview

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration();
    config.processPool = WKProcessPool()
    web = WKWebView(frame: self.frame, configuration: config)
```

I found from stactoverflow , that wkprocesspool can share cookie for multiple wkwebview  , but it seems like not working.... anyone help me~~~~pls

Comment: That should work. We do the same in Firefox for iOS. Are you sure all your `WKWebView` instances are using that same single `WKProcessPool` instance?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use shared WKProcessPool. But you instantiate a new instance each time.