# How to inject a cookie into WKWebView or WKWebSiteDataStore w/o JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, cookies, wkwebview

I'm trying to set a WKWebView process pool's per-domain cookie value explicitly / programatically. I want to emulate exactly what happens when a server sends back a `Set-Cookie` header. The research I've done here and elsewhere says to inject that as JavaScript. I don't like that on principle -- it feels wrong. I want to talk to the "guy in charge" (WebKit internal cookie data structure) not inject a hack at the last second through a second language (JavaScript).

I'm *also* getting a maddening 1% failure rate of this method, likely due to 1) The highly asynchronous nature of `WKWebView` interaction, since all the networking and JavaScript computation happens in a separate process and 2) The fact that I'm reusing the same `WKWebView` multiple times when a login session expires, and resetting the `document.cookie` script just before forcing the page to reload.

I'm surprised there's nothing like `WKWebSiteDataStore.addCookie(value: String, inDomain: NSURL)`; the fact that it has `removeDataOfTypes(...)` without `add` or `inject` screams "gaping design hole" to me.

References:

[ios9 - Multiple WkWebView sharing cookie WKProcessPool() doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839938/ios9-multiple-wkwebview-sharing-cookie-wkprocesspool-doesnt-work)

[Can I set the cookies to be used by a WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573137/can-i-set-the-cookies-to-be-used-by-a-wkwebview)

Answer (score 0):

Only iOS 11 supports this: [httpCookieStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebsitedatastore/2881956-httpcookiestore) (